# Файлы данных для android-приложения.

Tags: android, jni

Пишу приложение с использованием jni. Библиотеке на C++ требуются файлы с данными. Как их добавить в проект, и как их можно будет открывать из jni?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример: [тыц](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731314/android-ndk-write-file)

Добавляете в assets, а дальше используете обычный апи только сишный. Как пример выше по ссылке. Там пишется файл с данным и создается директория.
Если я конечно правильно понял ваш вопрос.

**UPD** Туда же: [тыц-два](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779955/android-assets-c-jni)

Comment: Т.е. сначала файлы надо вытащить из apk через AssetManager?

Comment: На мой взгляд для этой цели вам вообще Си не нужен. Используйте для этого Java-код. Си используется для ускорения медленных участков кода или для написания кроссплатформенных игровых движков.

Comment: Так и намеревался, вопрос только в том что, как я понял, из apk android сам вытаскивает только *.so а остальное достаётся с распаковкой на ходу.

Comment: Ну assets не пакуются и не шифруются, потому их можно вытащить как данные любого архива. Вот и вся разница по идеи.

Answer (score 1):

В общем скомбинировал и обработал найденное на stackoverflow. Получилось следующее.
В классе наследованном от Activity.

```
private void assetsToFiles() throws IOException { // распаковать файлы из assets
    File dir = getFilesDir();
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    String[] files = null;
    files = assetManager.list("");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    for(String filename : files) {
        File outfile = new File(dir, filename);
        if(outfile.exists()) continue;
        InputStream in;
        try{
            in = assetManager.open(filename, AssetManager.ACCESS_STREAMING);
        }catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
            continue;
        }
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outfile);
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
              out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Эту функцию вызываю из onCreate.
Нужные файлы помещаю в проекте в каталог assets.
А программе их следует искать в каталоге, путь к которому возвращает getFilesDir().

Блок try пришлось сделать из-за того, что assetManager.list почему-то возвращает в списке несуществующее имя "images".